# Force.com IDE does ONLY save to server when explicitely force by "Save to Server"

Tags: force.com, ide

When I save a change in my Force.com IDE this is not reflected on the server very often. I then have to manually use Force.com > Save to server.

I recently upgraded to Eclipse Juno but the problem remains.

Please note that I never turned "Build automatically" off. So this is not the reason for this misfunction. It only happens sometimes.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

If you have "build automatically" option set, then whenever you save the file locally Eclipse will try and save it to the server.

[image: Build Automatically menu option]

Otherwise you have to explicitly use "Force | Save to server".

--edit--
Since you have the build automatically checked, it must be something else. Perhaps the org is locked at the time because of running tests?
Have you looked at the Eclipse progress window? (you can add this to your view)
When you hit save, this should be where you see the status of the save to server when build automatically is checked.

[image: Progress window]

What do you see now in your progress window if you try and save? Is there an error message?

edit2--
Another possibility is that you have somehow enabled "work offline" mode on your project. In this case it will still do the "save to server" on demand but not for normal saves even when build automatically is on.
[image: Work offline option]

And when you select it you are warned
[image: Work offline warning]

edit3--
One quick check to make would be to ensure that the classes are referenced in your package.xml  Although, since you find it works when you manually "save to server" then this should not be the problem. Check this in Force.com | Add/remove Metadata Components and then ensure your class is listed there.

Other than that, can you try and pin down particular files that are affected? Is it a repeatable problem - try force "save to server" on a file.
Then add a line or comment and do a normal save.
Observe if the "polling server" progress appears.
Check in the Problems window for anything like this
[image: Problems window showing sync state error]

Once a file is out of sync you will need to resolve it and force save (this can happen if there is a problem communicating with the server or if someone else has updated the file and the instance copy is more up-to-date than your local one).

Comment: No errors at all. The UI behaves like in those cases where everything works. It's a bit faster but thats all...

Comment: So, does it actually show the "polling to server" progress bar? How are you aware that it's not been saved to the server? Do you get the warning "File only saved locally, not to server"?

Comment: I dont get that warning. Where should I see the Online Work menu? Its not in my context menu?!

Comment: You need to right click on the Force.com project (not on a lower level like src) and you should get that option on the Force.com popout menu.

Comment: Cool. But it is already in a Online mode. :(

Comment: Hey @DougB! Thank you very much for your extremely thorough answer.  I was having the exact same problem, but once I followed your advice to re-enable "work online" mode, everything worked like a charm.  Thanks!!

Comment: Glad that helped :)

Comment: BTW: This problem has dissolved without me having to do anything. And I am and was on Eclipse Juno. Even if it is not "supported" it is way better.

Comment: #3 fixed it for me

Comment: Why the hell it was in OFFLINE mode? I just downloaded a new instance of Eclipse, run it, install plugin, created a project. And didn't have a way to save changes. Ridiculous.

Comment: edit2 "work offline" worked for me once I made it "work online". Thank you!

Comment: thank you, 
I deactivate "build automatically" and now the page apex save correctly

Answer (score 20):

It is really hard to notice, but when project is 'Online' you will notice a blue square background in the small `X` icon in the top left of the project root icon folder, and it missing in 'Offline' mode.

However, please note that if 'Menu: Project > Build Automatically' is unselected working online **doesn’t seem to have any effect**.

[image: online-offline-icon-indicator-for-salesforce-eclipse-ide]

You can take it online by Right click on project folder --> Force.com --> Work Online.

[image]

Comment: is this an answer or just a comment? if its an answer, can you add more details on why its offline and how to avoid that or bring it back online.

Comment: This is the only answer that worked for me.

Comment: OMG - Thank you! I have been 'Working Offline' for a while now without realizing it. FYI rather then Navigator use Project Explorer view: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9991232/could-anyone-explain-the-exact-difference-among-project-explorer-package-explor

Answer (score 0):

Did you follow the instructions of Doug B. in Eclipse Juno or Helios? According to Salesforce you should be using Eclipse Helios as the most recent version of eclipse. Check it in http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Force.com_IDE_Installation