# New Force.com IDE not auto-deploying? (NOT A DUPLICATE QUESTION)

Tags: force.com, deployment, ide

I am having the same issue as here **[New Force.com IDE (Eclipse) - not auto-deploying?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/45076/new-force-com-ide-eclipse-not-auto-deploying)**, **except the solution chosen isn't working.**

**I have Build Automatically checked and I've also already selected "Work Online" for the entire project.**  These two actions are the only solutions made available under the above link. Nevertheless, every time I save the project, nothing saves to the production environment unless I manually go into each component and select "save to server" under the Force.com IDE menu item for that component.  I'm using Kepler 2 as well and the latest Force.com IDE Plugin.

I'm able to get the Sandbox Project I have to auto-deploy, just not in production.  I can also roll out new changes to the classes/vf pages via the changesets successfully (i.e., my test classes are working)

Please help, this is so annoying.

Comment: @LaceySnr as I mentioned in the original post, I've already tried the two solutions you marked as the duplicate and they don't work.

Comment: You can't save to Production though, you have to deploy. That's the rules.

Comment: To add on to what @DougB said, I have never deployed a change set from Eclipse to production.  I don't think you even can, create a change set in your sandbox and push it

Comment: @Doug B not true, in prior versions I could save directly to production.  Also see link above where jkraybill is able to save directly to production without deploying

Comment: @EricSSH you should try it some time, super-convenient, especially for minor changes in classes, you don't have to go through the whole deploy process.  it's one of the main reasons I use Eclipse

Comment: @StartingAgain, no place in his thread does he say he is saving to Production

Comment: Jeremy wasn't saving to produciton, just to a dev org. I know that because he phoned me before posting that day. You used to be able to save to production but it would run all tests on save, I think that was disabled a couple of years back now.

Comment: Ok, thanks everyone, I must have using an older version before the plugin got upgraded or something because I was definitely doing it. For anyone else that stumbles on this, you can always just right click on the component->force.com->save to server and that will deploy the changes in production...

Answer (score 0):

Is this something you encountered after latest summer '14 release ?
Please check the list of issues for force.com IDE to see if your issues is listed as known issue,

https://github.com/forcedotcom/idecore/issues