# Run the `.app` created in Eclipse Force.com IDE

Tags: lightning-apps, eclipse, ide, force.com-ide

How could I run the `.app` created in the Eclipse Force.com IDE?

By run I mean to perform a preview similar to the one I can perform in the developer console.

[Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6rXXrnnXqt8&t=768s) is the best example I was able to find so far. And I was not able to find any manual or examples which would explain the process in more details.

But here are a few questions I got after attempting to do the same as on the video:

1. What to do if I got an error when trying to `Save to Server`? The error is the following:

   > Unable to save resources: Filepath and/or project cannot be null.
   >   Reason: Filepath and/or project cannot be null

[This](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/11179/force-com-ide-does-only-save-to-server-when-explicitely-force-by-save-to-server) question give me a thought that maybe the problem is that everything was saved automatically and now I am trying to save the project which undergone no changes. So, I tried to set `Work online` for my project, perform a few tweaks in the project files and then save again and it still gives the same error.

[image]

2. After performing `Save to Server` the presenter on the video goes to the link to see the result of the saved `.app` (16:04 time of the video). So, how could I find the link I need to go to to preview me `.app`? [Here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.eclipse.meta/eclipse/eclipse_lightning_explore_lightning_app.htm) it is said that the link should be of type `https://yourDomain.lightning.force.com/c/hereAppNameGoes.app`. But where can I find my domain? I found the manual how to work with the domain over [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000002889&type=1).

In a nutshell what I need here is a documentation (or something like manual) on how to preview the `.app` created in the Eclipse Force.com IDE or answers to the questions above.

Comment: Is your project in eclipse even connected to your salesforce org?

Comment: @JayantDas, how could I check that? When I was creating the project I provided the login, password and security token. Does that mean that the project is connected to the org?

Comment: Refer to this [link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.eclipse.meta/eclipse/ProjectOrganizationPage.htm) for details on setting the properties. Seems like you don't have a connected org and furthermore, you need to login to the org to be able to view whatever you create in eclipse.